# Unit test for a component in angularJS 1.X (karma and Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-components

I have the component in angularJS 1.5

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('appLayout', {
      templateUrl: 'app/app-layout/app-layout.html',
      bindings: {
        envConfig: '<',
        categoriesByArea: '=',
        listCycles: '=',
        userRole: '='
      },
      controller: function ($log, $rootScope, ModalService, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        $rootScope.categoryList = vm.categoriesByArea;
        var error500 = $rootScope.$on('event:internalServerError', function () {
          _showError("ERROR 500", "Error");
        });
        $scope.$on('$destroy', error500);

        // PRIVATE FUNCTIONS
        function _showError(errorTitle, errorDescription) {
          $log.error('Error _showError', errorTitle, errorDescription);
          ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "app/shared/modals/modal-error.html",
            controller: "ModalErrorController",
            inputs: {
              errorTitle: errorTitle,
              errorDescription: errorDescription
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
})();
```

I have created the test according to the official docs from Angular https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#unit-testing-component-controllers

```js
describe('component: appLayout', function () {
  var $componentController;
  var rootScope;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$componentController_) {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
  }));

  // Here we are passing actual bindings to the component
  var bindings = {
    envConfig: {"api": "http://localhost:8080", "env": "local", "version": "1.7.2"},
    categoriesByArea: {},
    listCycles: {},
    userRole: {}
  };

  it('should expose a `appLayout` object', function () {
    var ctrl = $componentController('appLayout', null, bindings);

    expect(ctrl.envConfig).toBeDefined();
    expect(ctrl.categoriesByArea).toBeDefined();
    expect(ctrl.listCycles).toBeDefined();
    expect(ctrl.userRole).toBeDefined();

    expect(ctrl.envConfig.api).toBe('http://localhost:8080');
    expect(ctrl.envConfig.env).toBe('local');
    expect(ctrl.envConfig.version).toBe('1.7.2');
  });
});
```

But this is covering just the component but not the controller of that component.

what is the best approach to cover this 100%?

Comment: Since nobody commented here, I 'll give it a shot. Actually you have your controller in the "ctrl" var, so you can test it. If you want to instrument _showError you can put a spy on it. You can make a fake ModalService and test that its method "showModal" is called